# Using gnome-keyring with svn via ssh and mysql-workbench

Tags: gnome, ssh, mysql, keyrings

Problem: mysql-workbench fails to connect to the keyring to connect to mysql.

I'm trying to get my svn command (which uses an svn+ssh uri) to prompt me to enter my password for my local rsa secrets.  Basically, I connected via ssh to the server which hosts svn, and copied over my public key into the .ssh folder in the authorized_keys2 file.  My rsa id is protected by a password so that after I login, I still need to enter the rsa password to connect to the other machine. (Forgive me if my terminology isn't correct).

This works great.  Now, I can also run ssh-add to enter my password once the entire time I'm logged in.  This works fabulous too.  I realize that I never remember to run ssh-add before I run 'svn update', so I get the idea from websearches that I could use the keyring to automatcially pop up a dialog box whenever I do a subversion update.

So, I add the following to my .profile:

```
# Add ssh to the gnome keyring components
eval $(/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=ssh)
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Once I do this, I see that the ssh-agent is still set in my environment variables.  So, I use xfconf-query to set the xfce4-session parameter of /startup/ssh-agent/enabled to false.  Great, now My environment variable for the SSH_AUTH_SOCK is using the keyring.

But...  mysql-workbench can no longer access the keyring to log in and perform queries.

When I remove the eval and export from my .profile, then mysql-workbench works.  When I run the commands manually, mysql-workbench still works, and so does the keyring popup on my svn.

How do I get both the mysql-workbench and svn's ssh request to use the keyring with startup options?
(ie what n00bie mistake am I making in my attempts to make the gnome-keyring work?)

I also tried editng the /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop to 'OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;XFCE;', but that had no apparent affect.

```
Xubuntu: 12.04
Xfce: 4.8
Mysql Workbench: 5.2.38
OpenSsh: 5.9p1
gnome-keyring: 3.2.2
```

Comment: Noo-ne noo-ne noo.